# Lag when opening Data Manager Settings

Tags: data-connection, motorola-defy

Since I have a prepaid Internet/Data Plan, I need to turn off/on Data Connection frequently. But Navigating to `Settings -> Data Manager` takes at least 25-30s on my Moto Defy (2.2) device. What could be the problem?

EDIT : As a workaround I am using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.neko.freewing.MobileDataOnOff&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwianAubmUubmVrby5mcmVld2luZy5Nb2JpbGVEYXRhT25PZmYiXQ..) app to turn on/off. Have installed and uninstalled lots of other widgets which never worked.

Comment: When you say "Navigating to Settings -> Data Manager takes atleast 25-30s on my moto defy (2.2) device." Why does the process take so long? Where is it slow?

Comment: @Peanut After I tap on Data Manager it doesn't open up immediately. it shows a blank screen and loads the menu after 30s. [This](http://androidforums.com/motorola-milestone-2/315523-settings-data-manager-very-slow-10-30-seconds-show-up-why.html) is the same problem I have but there was no solution as to how the OP fixed it.